# Merge statement help in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, oracle11g

I am using merge for the 1 st time ... I went through existing questions but couldn't get proper help.

Please help me with the below need,

I have a table "table_a" with 3 columns A, B and C. C is a new column added combination of column A and B are unique, to be specific column B is a list of sub codes taken from table_b and configured against the entity in column A.

I need to update column C with a hard coded value for the existing A and B combinations and if some subcode  missing from table_b in table_a I need to insert the rows for the same in table_a.

eg. table_a

```
A    B   C                              
=    =   =
p    x
p    y
```

table_b

```
M
=
x
y
z
```

After execution of query

table_a

```
A    B   C                              
=    =   =
p    x   1   -- updated with column C
p    y   1   -- updated with column C
p    z   1   -- new row inserted for the row in table_b
```

Kindly let me know if anything is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MERGE INTO table_A a
   USING table_b b
      ON(a.b = b.m)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN 
      UPDATE SET a.c = 1
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
      INSERT (a, b, c)
      VALUES ('P', b.m, 1)
```

Note : The insert has two hardcode values for column a and column c as 'P' and 1 respectively.

Comment: won't run - a.a doesn't exist

Comment: Correct, got confused with table alias and column name. Needs to be hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hard-code the inserted values you can use an in-line view to generate all the expected combinations and merge against that.

```
merge into table_a a
using (
  select t.a, b.m, 1 as c
  from (select distinct a from table_a) t
  cross join table_b b
) b
on (a.b = b.m)
when matched then
  update set a.c = b.c
when not matched then
  insert (a, b, c) values (b.a, b.m, b.c);
```

The `using` clause does a cross-join of all (distinct) `table_a.a` values against all `table_b.m` values, to give all possible combinations. (Which seems to be what you want; you haven't shown any other link between the two). I've also included the fixed value `1` in that view.

Then the merge either sets `c` for the rows the matching values that already exit in `table_a`, or inserts a new row using the values from the in-line view.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ec74a/2).

You might be able to get your unique `a` values from some other look-up table, which would be better than hitting `table_a` twice, but that depends on your real data model.

Comment: Thanks alex, Actually my case doesn't need hard coding of column a but the choosing of table_b varies with the value configured in table_a.a...   I can say a example if table_a the cvolumn a is configured as 'FRUITS' then the table_b is some table_fruits in column b of table_a i ll configure all the values present in table_fruits..... in second case say the table_a.a = 'automobile' then i ll use some other table say table_automobile and i need to configure all the rows of table_automobile in to table_a.b column with table_a.a='automobile'.not sure If I can  achive it using bulk and case here

Comment: @PavanKumar - that's really well beyond the scope of this question. You should ask a new question about that, preferably with a more complete data sample and problem description. But first you could see if you can find a way to get the final result set just as a query - that would then become the `using` subquery.

Comment: For now I have already delevered giving multiple statements for different values of  table_a.a . will surely try out for a single query with what ever you suggested. Thank you again for the help..